# Is there a way in Safari to let https images load on the page without it having a secure connection?

Tags: image, https, safari

When loading the site in Safari, I have some images that use a https link, the images do not display on the page, when I open the image URL in the browser, it will not load, saying "Safari can't open the page X because Safari can't establish a secure connection to the server X". This needs to use https links for the images, is there a header or something I can set to allow this to load?

I have tried removing the https, and images load in http, the site we get the images from are used from an API and they they return the image link to use, this does not have an SSL cert on it

not any code, a general question about a setting in Safari if we can avoid using any manual changes that a user will not make on their own.

Expect that the image will load up and thus on the pages that we want to display the images on.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this one here:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/275522/unable-to-load-https-websites-on-safari
The issue is that Safari won't support in older versions the TLS protocol in use in modern-day browsers. I wasn't aware it would be such an old version in use for windows users.

[image: Source from wikipedia]